# Unable to parse json file in uitable view

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, ios7

Hi friends i am facing problem with parsing json file in to uitableview.
My json files looks like this :

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Deal Closed",
    "score": 100,
    "createdAt": "2014-10-03T08:10:10.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-10-03T08:10:10.000Z"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "Followers",
    "score": 10,
    "createdAt": "2014-10-03T08:10:28.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2014-10-03T08:10:28.000Z"
    }
]
```

My coding is here..

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Leader";    
NSString *firstname = [[promoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"type"];
NSString *lastname = [[promoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"score"];
cell.lblPrice.text=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"type"];
cell.lblDesc.text=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"score"];
```

it throws exception..while parsing. i need to parse type and score from json file to Uitable view.

Comment: 1. There is no JSON. This is not parsing it is just accessing items from an array or dictionaries. 2. `firstname` and `lastname` are never used. 3. Which line is creating the exception and whjat is the error message. Add a global exception breakpoint if you don't have one already.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust to this:

```
cell.lblPrice.text=jsonDict[indexPath.row][@"type"];
cell.lblDesc.text= jsonDict[indexPath.row][@"score"];
```

Comment: it will work if i add more number of datas in json files

Comment: yes it will work. and your variable names are confusing

Comment: then i need to remove promo array ?

Comment: promo, first name, price type or score, Im lost you should show me the function itself